# How to use concat and group by together in SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm facing an issue when typing group by after writing the function `CONCAT` to combine two columns of my table. The error is

> SELECT list expressions references column which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Here is my query

```sql
SELECT
concat(state,':', warehouse_alias) As warehouse_name,
count(orders.order_id) as num_of_orders,
(select count(*) from `inlaid-agility-409401.warehouse_orders.orders` ) as total_orders
FROM `inlaid-agility-409401.warehouse_orders.warehouse` As warehouse
left join `inlaid-agility-409401.warehouse_orders.orders` As orders
on warehouse.warehouse_id=orders.warehouse_id
group by warehouse.warehouse_id,warehouse_alias
```

The error is related to `concat`

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP BY concat(state, ':', warehouse_alias)`?